# Error Invalid Conversion from runtime JSON to APEX

Tags: httprequest, httpresponse

I am getting an error while converting the response from JSON to Apex class.

```
Invalid conversion from runtime type MapAPIDemo.resourceSets to List<MapAPIDemo.resourceSets>
```

Here is the code below

**Apex Code**

```
public with sharing class MapAPIDemo {

    public list<resourceSets> listresourceSet{get;set;}
    public Integer statusCode{get;set;}
    public String copyright{get;set;}
    public String statusDescription{get;set;}
    public String brandLogoUri{get;set;}
    public String traceId{get;set;}
    public String authenticationResultCode{get;set;}
   
   
   
   
    public static void getPostalCodeDetails(String postalCode){
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String endPoint = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?postalCode=';
        endPoint += postalCode;
        endPoint += '&key=';
        endPoint += SYSTEM.Label.BING_API;
        request.setEndPoint(endPoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
            System.debug('Code Results=====>'+response.getStatus());
            String responseBody = response.getBody();
            //List<MapAPIDemo.resourceSets> lstResource = (List<MapAPIDemo.resourceSets>) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),MapAPIDemo.resourceSets.class);

            //system.debug('resourceSets====>'+lstResource);

        }

        

    }

   


    public class resourceSets{
        public list<resources> resources{get;set;}
        public Integer estimatedTotal{get;set;}
    }

    public class resources{
        public String entityType{get;set;}
        public String confidence{get;set;}
        public point point{get;set;}
        public address address{get;set;}
        public String name{get;set;}
        public list<geocodePoints> geocodePoints{get;set;}
        public list<String> bbox{get;set;}
        public list<String> matchCodes{get;set;}
        public String locType{get;set;}
    }

    public class point{
        public list<String> coordinates{get;set;}
        public String type{get;set;}
    }


    public class geocodePoints{
        public String type{get;set;}
        public String calculationMethod{get;set;}
        public list<String> usageTypes{get;set;}
        public list<String> coordinates{get;set;}
    }

    public class address{
        public String postalCode{get;set;}
        public String countryRegion{get;set;}
        public String formattedAddress{get;set;}
        public String adminDistrict2{get;set;}
        public String locality{get;set;}
        public String adminDistrict{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Please provide the json your trying to parse

Answer (score 1):

From given error -

```
Invalid conversion from runtime type MapAPIDemo.resourceSets to List<MapAPIDemo.resourceSets>
```

You are **not** using **list type** in `JSON.deserialize` method.

Please try with this code part -

```java
List<MapAPIDemo.resourceSets> lstResource = (List<MapAPIDemo.resourceSets>) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<MapAPIDemo.resourceSets>.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting an error now System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan That means your JSON isn't a list, but rather a single object.

Comment: Ysr, please use *please* instead of *pls*. Some people may consider it unprofessional, and one of our core tenants is that we want to be taken as if we were professional.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for the feedback. I have updated the answer and I will take care in future as well. :)